# IMF data downloading bug

Tags: json, r, utf-8

I'm facing bug, which starting to make me really nervous. 
So, begin from the start: I writed a code, which downloads data from IMF DOT (countries export ad import data). 
Sometime this code works (downloads all data). Sometime. Other time, in middle of downloading i get error:

```
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//
                     (right here) ------^
```

What is funny there - sometime error happens in the beggining of downloading, sometime in the middle. Basically, it comes random. So debugging it is basically fighting with shadow. Maybe anyone has faced with this problem also and can help?

```
Code: 

   rm(list = ls())
#Code downloads data from DOT (IMF). 
#DOT(date).csv

# Libraries
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(plyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(reshape2))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(stringr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(IMFData))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(TTR))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(readxl))

#Parameters of download -------------------------------------------------------

databaseID <- 'DOT'
startdate <- '1977-01-01'
enddate <- format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d")
checkquery = FALSE

  # Frequency
download.freq <- c("A")

  # Area
available.codes <- DataStructureMethod('DOT')
cn <- available.codes$CL_AREA_DOT


# Download data -----------------------------------------------------------

print("Downloading")
datalist <- list(); queryfilter<- list()
for(i in 1:length(cn[,"CodeValue"])) queryfilter[[i]] <- list(CL_FREA=download.freq, CL_AREA_DOT=cn[,"CodeValue"][i],  CL_INDICATOR_DOT = "TXG_FOB_USD"
)

datalist<- plyr::llply(queryfilter, function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(runif(1,2,5))
  Dot.downloader(databaseID,x, startdate, enddate) 
}, .progress = "text")

#WHERE ERRORS HAPPENS

data <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, datalist) #..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Oh and Dot.downloader function looks like this (it is from IMFdata library, just a bit adapted to the situation):

```
    Dot.downloader <- function(databaseID, queryfilter=NULL,
                           startdate='1977-01-01', enddate='2016-12-31'){

  queryfilterstr <- ''
  if (length(queryfilter) > 0){
    queryfilterstr <- paste0(
      unlist(plyr::llply(queryfilter,
                         function(x)(paste0(x, collapse="+")))), collapse=".")
  }

  APIstr <- paste0('http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/CompactData/',
                   databaseID,'/',queryfilterstr,
                   '?startPeriod=',startdate,'&endPeriod=',enddate)
  r <- httr::GET(APIstr)

  if(httr::http_status(r)$reason != "OK"){
    stop(paste(unlist(httr::http_status(r))))
    return(list())
  }
  r.parsed <- jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(r, "text"))

  if(is.null(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series)){
    warning("No data available")
    return(NULL)
  }

  if(class(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series) == "data.frame"){
    r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series <- r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series[!plyr::laply(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series$Obs, is.null),]
    if(nrow(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series) ==0){
      warning("No data available")
      return(NULL)
    }
  }

  if(class(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series) == "list"){
    if(is.null(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series$Obs)){
      warning("No data available")
      return(NULL)
    }
    ret.df <- as.data.frame(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series[1:(length(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series)-1)])
    ret.df$Obs <- list(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series$Obs)
    names(ret.df) <- names(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series)
    r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series <- ret.df
  }

  return(r.parsed$CompactData$DataSet$Series)
}
```